# Caching Objects - Specific Use-case

Tags: caching, nosql, memcached

Currently All the data are stored in Data-Base. I want to cache all students in university , so that application would not connect every time to data-base and then wants to query from cache like

Here is sample objects and relation among them in my application.

University
    --- contains Number of Collages

Collage 
    --- contains Number of Courses.

Course 
    --- contains Numbers of Students

(Forget about size of data)

Get all students of university.
Get all students of course "TP".
Get all students of collage "ABC".

Can anyone help to achieve this ? or suggest me any API that support this.

Any help is appreciated !!!

Cheers,
Sanjiv Singh

Comment: It would help to know what language you're using. Just to let you know though, your RDBMS should cache automatically.

Comment: This is sample data-model....we are using OpenLDAP as data store.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the Select statement to fetch all elements of the table but you have to make a condition i.e join for all student of the university.
1. take join of all tables for all students of the universities
2. take join of all tables where course.id="TP"

but you have to use ids correctly private and foriegn so as make a good relationship.

You may also see:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp